# Cannot load database model in rails c production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

aliyun Elastic Compute Service

```
app_danci@iZ2ze599ua4y0nvsppbmjhZ:~/myproject$ rails c -e production

Running via Spring preloader in process 13978

Loading production environment (Rails 5.1.4)

2.3.1 :001 > u = User.first

NameError: uninitialized constant User

    from (irb):1

2.3.1 :002 > User.all

NameError: uninitialized constant User

    from (irb):2
```

Why can I not see the model User?

Comment: If you run in development mode (without -e ...) it works as expected?

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP. Both development and production db exist, but when running `rails c production`, I also got `NameError (uninitialized constant User)`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing something. I think you have a migration for a `users` table. Have you run `rails db:migrate`? If so, maybe you have just the table but you have not defined the class `User`?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

or maybe is your class `User` defined inside a module?

Comment: My web is running OK, so the database is OK when web running. But when i want to see some datas in several models like as User using "rails c -e production" in aliyun ECS, the result is what i posted yesterday. I cannot understand why?

Answer (score 0):

The common error, one can make is not using appropriate nested Namespaces. If your `models` are defined under a `namespace` please use it in your console too. It can be called by using a qualifying names such as `::Namespace::Model`. It is highly unlikely that `rails console` loads fine and can't seem to call the Rails Model. Hope this helps.